Fetch API cannot load <URL>. Request mode is "no-cors" but the redirect mode is not "follow"
I have this issue only in Brave browser when I disable the Shield. I have OWA analytics file on my blog:
https://stats.jcubic.pl/modules/base/js/owa.tracker-combined-min.js

And I use my Service Worker library called Wayne on my blog. The library intercept all requests and allow creating pure in browser HTTP responses. Similar to Express.js do in Node but in Service Worker. It also has similar API. I'm using the library to add syntax highlighting to the JavaScript and CSS files when you open them in the browser.
But I got this error:

Fetch API cannot load https://stats.jcubic.pl/modules/base/js/owa.tracker-combined-min.js. Request mode is "no-cors" but the redirect mode is not "follow".

The file don't have any redirect. Domain stats.jcubic.pl have CORS enabled.
The error originate from this code (stripped from irrelevant parts):
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
    if (filter(event.request) === false) {
        return;
    }
    const promise = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const req = event.request;
        try {
            // Wayne logic with early return
            if (event.request.cache === 'only-if-cached' &&
                event.request.mode !== 'same-origin') {
                return;
            }
            
            fetch(event.request).then(resolve).catch(reject);
        } catch(error) {
            this._handle_error(resolve, req, error);
        }
    });
    event.respondWith(promise.catch(() => {}));
});

I don't know what this line if (event.request.cache ... is doing, found it in some example.
Why this error happen, and how can I get rid of it when I intercept all requests? I'm trying to understand what is the reason for this error, but also want to know how to fix this if there is a way.
I would prefer to fix this in the Wayne library itself so it's fixed also for other users, not only for my blog.
Just to be complete, this is a code snippet to add OWA to my blog:
  <script type="text/javascript">
   //<![CDATA[
   var owa_baseUrl = 'https://stats.jcubic.pl/';
   var owa_cmds = owa_cmds || [];
   owa_cmds.push(['setSiteId', 'b9a1a51b38e3837c9a5b309ec4122ff3']);
   owa_cmds.push(['trackPageView']);
   owa_cmds.push(['trackClicks']);
   (function() {
       var _owa = document.createElement('script'); _owa.type = 'text/javascript'; _owa.async = true;
       owa_baseUrl = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? window.owa_baseSecUrl || owa_baseUrl.replace(/http:/, 'https:') : owa_baseUrl );
       _owa.src = owa_baseUrl + 'modules/base/js/owa.tracker-combined-min.js';
       var _owa_s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; _owa_s.parentNode.insertBefore(_owa, _owa_s);
   }());
   //]]>
  </script>

It's obviously the same URL that doesn't have any direct.
I've tried to add _owa.crossorigin = ''; to the above snippet but no difference.
I was thinking of add a flag called skip to the fetch event, but the problem is that the Promise callback is async (there is no other way to write this code, there is try..catch so all problems with async are handled).

If the issue only occurs in a single browser with a particular setting, perhaps create an issue on that github repo. The author would probably be able to fix such an issue easier, since they understand the library

Also, can you add the relevant part of YOUR code that triggers the error (clearly, it's some fetch that does so

@JaromandaX this is my library and the code with fetch is included in the question. I think that this is a bug in Brave. Because this happens only on a file that is blocked by Shield when it's on.

oh ... well, that's embarrassing for me

Do I understand it right: Your service worker is meant to add syntax highlighting to source code that is shown in your blog, but it adds it even to the OWA library from stats.jcubic.pl that you want to execute in your browser? I assume the highlighted Javascript code is no longer valid text/javascript.

@HeikoTheißen no, this not what I said. You can only add syntax highlight to urls you open in new tab. You can control other domain with service worker only when script originate from controlled page like with fetch
